# How to check when taxonomy vocabulary was changed Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

i have vocabulary with name dish_type, i need to clear specific cache when it was saved, i tried to make `hook_taxonomy_overview_terms_submit()`, also for `hook_taxonomy_vocabulary_update()` but it didnt work.
Is there a way to track this? 
Please need your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated hook_taxonomy_vocabulary_presave($vocabulary) as a possible solution?  This will be called before your vocabulary is saved, and I should think updated.  You could then do a cache_clear_all($cid = NULL, $bin = NULL, $wildcard = FALSE).

Comment: No didnt work, i know that that is form.
'<form action="/en/admin/structure/taxonomy/my_vocabulary" method="post" id="taxonomy-overview-terms" accept-charset="UTF-8">'
Maybe is a way to catch that submit

Answer (score 0):

Use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add a custom submit handler on taxonomy add/edit form.

Code sample:

```
function [YOUR_MOUDLE]_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id === 'taxonomy_form_term' && is_numeric(arg(2)) && arg(3) === 'edit') {
        $form['#submit'][] = '[YOUR_MOUDLE]_custom_submit_handler';
    }
}

function [YOUR_MOUDLE]_custom_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
    // Code to be executed on taxonomy update
}
```